# USB headphones get no sound when I use Mplayer and Alsa built from source

Tags: usb, alsa

I recently built Mplayer and Alsa from source, and when I play a video through the player, I don't get sound through my USB headphones.

However, if I rebuild Mplayer and configure it to use the preinstalled Alsa library, it works as intended.

Even if I build Alsa using the same the version as the one that came preinstalled in my system, I keep experiencing sound problems with the USB headphones.

So, what am I missing?

Edit: configure command:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Freetype-2.3.2/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Openssl-1.1.1b/lib/pkgconfig/ 
./configure --prefix=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Mplayer-1.4/ \
  --enable-openssl-nondistributable --extra-cflags=" \
  -I /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/X11-1.4.4/include/ 
  -I /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xorgproto-2018.1/include/ 
  -I /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Alsa-1.0.21/include/ 
  -I /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xext-1.1.1/include/ 
  -I /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Zlib-1.2.11/include/" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Alsa-1.0.21/lib/ 
  -L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Zlib-1.2.11/lib/ 
  -Wl,-rpath=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Zlib-1.2.11/lib/ 
  -L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xext-1.1.1/lib/ 
  -Wl,-rpath=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/Xext-1.1.1/lib/ 
  -L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/X11-1.4.4/lib/ 
  -Wl,-rpath=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/xorg/X11-1.4.4/lib/ 
  -Wl,-rpath=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Freetype-2.3.2/lib/"
```

Comment: I guess your forgot some `configure` flags or assimilated while building Alsa by your own.

Comment: We'd need your full build output, including bootstrap and configure steps to answer what is missing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added my configure command to my post. I don't know what bootstrap means and I am unsure about what do you mean by "full build output"? It can't be all make's output, perhaps the last part?

Comment: We'd need the **output** of that configure run, though, to see whether configure complained about something missing and hence disabling something. And I'm more betting on libalsa than on mplayer - mplayer has no idea about how devices are connected.

Comment: @MarcusMüller. Config.log says complains about nothing on its Alsa detection test. The full test is probably too large to attach here, but perhaps I could host it somewhere else (where?). I can do the same with alsa.